# UML Statemachine - Reuse state

Tags: uml, state-machine, fsm

I'm trying to model a state machine which reuses a state in order to reduce complexity. 
I've got three states: State A, B and X.

My state X can either be entered via a transaction from state A or B.

State X includes multiple substates with lots of complexity and I don't wont to implement it twice.

After the process in state X is completed I need to transition back to back to state A or B based on which one was the previous state.

Is there a elegant way to solve this?

Comment: @Thomas I've looked into history and deep history. However I don't think this would work because state B itself is actually part of a substate. So there would be multiple pseudo hostory states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *SubMachine* will help you to reuse several time part of your state modelling.
But if you want to be able to enter into your state X from A or B and then retun to the previous state, *ShallowHistory* Would be a good idea.

In the following state machine, I modeled a SubMachine X referenced by both states X1 and X2. I also wanted to model the fact that state X2 in processed after A or B and then next state if the previous one.

[image]

Another solution consists in playing with transition guards or events/triggers. You must keep in mind that transitions are triggered when specific events occurs or when its guard is true cf. following screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> State X includes multiple substates with lots of complexity and I don't wont to implement it twice

Define a *submachine* corresponding to your state X and in your current machine use *submachine state* to instantiate it where you need

See §14.2.3.4.7 Submachine States and submachines page 311 in [formal-17-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) :

> Submachines are a means by which a single StateMachine specification can be reused multiple times. They are similar to encapsulated composite States in that they need to bind incoming and outgoing Transitions to their internal Vertices.
>
> ...
>
> NOTE. Each submachine State represents a distinct instantiation of a submachine, even when two or more submachine States reference the same submachine.